# How to ingest a large Stream table using Snowflake Task?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, debezium, snowflake-connector

I am using the Snowflake Kafka Sink Connector to ingest data from Debezium into a Snowflake table. I have created a Stream and a Task on this table. As the data from Kafka lands into the source table, the stream gets populated and the task runs a `MERGE` command to write the data into a final table.

However, as the stream has grown moderately large with about 50 million rows, the task fails to run to completion and times out.

To address this, I have tried the following:

1. Increase the timeout of the task from 1 hour to 24 hours.
2. Increase the warehouse size to Medium.

The task still doesn't finish after 24 hours and times out.

Is it the case that ingesting 50M rows requires an even larger warehouse to ingest these rows? How do I get the task to run to completion?

### `MERGE` statement

```
MERGE INTO TARGET.MESSAGE AS P
        USING (SELECT RECORD_CONTENT:payload:before.id::VARCHAR          AS BEFORE_ID,
                      RECORD_CONTENT:payload:before.agency_id::VARCHAR   AS BEFORE_AGENCY_ID,
                      RECORD_CONTENT:payload:after.id::VARCHAR           AS AFTER_ID,
                      RECORD_CONTENT:payload:after.agency_id::VARCHAR    AS AFTER_AGENCY_ID,
                      RECORD_CONTENT:payload:after::VARIANT              AS PAYLOAD,
                      RECORD_CONTENT:payload:source.ts_ms::INT           AS TS_MS,
                      RECORD_CONTENT:payload:op::VARCHAR                 AS OP
               FROM RAW.MESSAGE_STREAM
                   QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                       PARTITION BY COALESCE(AFTER_ID, BEFORE_ID), COALESCE(AFTER_AGENCY_ID, BEFORE_AGENCY_ID)
                       ORDER BY TS_MS DESC
                       ) = 1) PS ON (P.ID = PS.AFTER_ID AND P.AGENCY_ID = PS.AFTER_AGENCY_ID) OR
                                    (P.ID = PS.BEFORE_ID AND P.AGENCY_ID = PS.BEFORE_AGENCY_ID)
        WHEN MATCHED AND PS.OP = 'd' THEN DELETE
        WHEN MATCHED AND PS.OP IN ('u', 'r') THEN UPDATE SET P.PAYLOAD = PS.PAYLOAD, P.TS_MS = PS.TS_MS
        WHEN NOT MATCHED AND PS.OP IN ('c', 'r', 'u') THEN INSERT (P.ID, P.AGENCY_ID, P.PAYLOAD, P.TS_MS) VALUES (PS.AFTER_ID, PS.AFTER_AGENCY_ID, PS.PAYLOAD, PS.TS_MS);
```

### `EXPLAIN` Plan

```
GlobalStats:
    partitionsTotal=742
    partitionsAssigned=742
    bytesAssigned=3596441600
Operations:
1:0     ->Result  number of rows inserted, number of rows updated, number of rows deleted  
1:1          ->WindowFunction  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IFNULL(TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'after'), 'id')), TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'before'), 'id'))), IFNULL(TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'after'), 'agency_id')), TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'before'), 'agency_id'))) ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'source'), 'ts_ms')) DESC NULLS FIRST)  
1:2               ->LeftOuterJoin  joinFilter: ((P.ID = (TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'after'), 'id')))) AND (P.AGENCY_ID = (TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'after'), 'agency_id'))))) OR ((P.ID = (TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'before'), 'id')))) AND (P.AGENCY_ID = (TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'before'), 'agency_id')))))  
1:3                    ->Filter  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IFNULL(TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'after'), 'id')), TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'before'), 'id'))), IFNULL(TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'after'), 'agency_id')), TO_CHAR(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'before'), 'agency_id'))) ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(GET(GET(GET(UNION_ALL(CHANGES."a_RECORD_CONTENT", CHANGES."d_RECORD_CONTENT"), 'payload'), 'source'), 'ts_ms')) DESC NULLS FIRST) = 1  
1:4                         ->UnionAll  
1:5                              ->Filter  CHANGES.A_METADATA$ACTION IS NOT NULL  
1:6                                   ->WithReference  
1:7                                        ->WithClause  CHANGES  
1:8                                             ->Filter  (A.METADATA$SHORTNAME IS NULL) OR (D.METADATA$SHORTNAME IS NULL) OR (NOT(EQUAL_NULL(SCAN_FDN_FILES.RECORD_METADATA, SCAN_FDN_FILES.RECORD_METADATA))) OR (NOT(EQUAL_NULL(SCAN_FDN_FILES.RECORD_CONTENT, SCAN_FDN_FILES.RECORD_CONTENT)))  
1:9                                                  ->FullOuterJoin  joinKey: (D.METADATA$ROW_ID = A.METADATA$ROW_ID) AND (D.METADATA$SHORTNAME = A.METADATA$SHORTNAME)  
1:10                                                       ->TableScan  DATABASE.RAW.MESSAGE as SCAN_FDN_FILES  METADATA$PARTITION_ROW_NUMBER, METADATA$PARTITION_NAME, RECORD_METADATA, RECORD_CONTENT, METADATA$ORIGINAL_PARTITION_NAME, METADATA$ORIGINAL_PARTITION_ROW_NUMBER  {partitionsTotal=17, partitionsAssigned=17, bytesAssigned=20623360}
1:11                                                       ->TableScan  DATABASE.RAW.MESSAGE as SCAN_FDN_FILES  METADATA$PARTITION_ROW_NUMBER, METADATA$PARTITION_NAME, RECORD_METADATA, RECORD_CONTENT, METADATA$ORIGINAL_PARTITION_NAME, METADATA$ORIGINAL_PARTITION_ROW_NUMBER  {partitionsTotal=507, partitionsAssigned=507, bytesAssigned=3519694336}
1:12                              ->Filter  CHANGES.D_METADATA$ACTION IS NOT NULL  
1:13                                   ->WithReference  
1:14                    ->TableScan  DATABASE.TARGET.MESSAGE as P  ID, AGENCY_ID  {partitionsTotal=218, partitionsAssigned=218, bytesAssigned=56123904}
```

### Query Profile

[Query Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nknne.png)

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to have a let a stream grow to 50M records before you processed it; ideally you should load historic records to clear the backlog and then load from the stream more frequently. However, given the situation you are in, please update your question with the MERGE statement you are running and the EXPLAIN PLAN for that statement

Comment: On the Medium instance is there remote spilling occurring? at which point you might need to do smaller reads from the stream. Also what are the expensive operations in the SQL, perhaps you are doing some explensive cross join, and some preconditioning of your data for an equi-join might boost your performance.

Comment: @NickW I've updated the question with the `MERGE` statement and the `EXPLAIN` plan. To clarify, the Task was supposed to run every minute to process data from the stream as it arrived from Kafka. However, as data arrived from Kafka faster than the task could process, it reached 50M rows.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I used the Query Details to check and I could see spilling to disk "Bytes spilled to local storage 2.37GB" There was no remote spilling happening. I've updated the question with a snapshot.

Comment: YA, so it the cost seems to be that LEFT OUTER JOIN aka the ON with the OR clause.

Comment: looking at the explain plan, it appear to be doing the JOIN before the ROW_NUMBER filtering.. that seems broken.. I don't feel this query should be taking all this time..

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Is it something that can be optimised?

Comment: I just suggested two things to try on clones, the first is the same code, just written more simple. To see what the optimizer makes of it.

Comment: and now I have suggested a way to get around the "current stuck" part, by breaking the task into two steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-jiggled you SQL just so it's more readable to me..

```
MERGE INTO target.message AS p
    USING (
    SELECT 
        record_content:payload:before.id::VARCHAR          AS before_id,
        record_content:payload:before.agency_id::VARCHAR   AS before_agency_id,
        record_content:payload:after.id::VARCHAR           AS after_id,
        record_content:payload:after.agency_id::VARCHAR    AS after_agency_id,
        record_content:payload:after::VARIANT              AS payload,
        record_content:payload:source.ts_ms::INT           AS ts_ms,
        record_content:payload:op::VARCHAR                 AS op,
        COALESCE(after_id, before_id) AS id_a
        COALESCE(after_agency_id, before_agency_id) AS id_b
    FROM raw.message_stream
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_a, id_b ORDER BY ts_ms DESC ) = 1
) AS ps 
    ON (p.id = ps.after_id AND p.agency_id = ps.after_agency_id) OR
       (p.id = ps.before_id AND p.agency_id = ps.before_agency_id)
WHEN MATCHED AND ps.op = 'd' 
    THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND ps.op IN ('u', 'r') 
    THEN UPDATE SET p.payload = ps.payload, p.ts_ms = ps.ts_ms
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ps.op IN ('c', 'r', 'u') 
    THEN INSERT (p.id, p.agency_id, p.payload, p.ts_ms) 
        VALUES (ps.after_id, ps.after_agency_id, ps.payload, ps.ts_ms);
```

I don't see anything super horrible here. I push the COALESCE of the two values used in the QUALIFY into the SELECT just so I can read it simpler.

But looking the ON logic, you are prepared to match before's if after's don't match, but mixing that with the COALESCE logic are the two after values both null at the same time? aka if `after_id` is null, `after_agency_id` will also be null. Because then if ALSO you don't want to care about check "before" if the "after" are not null but don't match. Then you could use:

```
ON p.id = ps.id_a AND p.agency_id = ps.id_b
```

albeit, you might want to name them better then. That should improve it a simdge.

Back to the JOIN logic, another reason I think the above might apply is you are grouping/partitioning the ROW_NUMBER by the after values if present, which implies if you had values with the same after values, and different before values, due to the current ROW_NUMBER the later might be getting thrown away.

But otherwise it doesn't look like it's doing anything "truely bad" at which point you might want to run a 4-8 times bigger warehouse, and let it for 24/8 hours and see if it completes in 10% extra time. The cost of the bigger warehouse should be offset in the small real clock time.

### Silly Idea:

on the smaller data set you mention, try the SQL made real nice and simple:

```
MERGE INTO target.message AS p
USING (
    (
    SELECT 
        b.before_id,
        b.before_agency_id,
        b.after_id,
        b.after_agency_id,
        b.payload,
        b.ts_ms,
        b.op,
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            A.*
            ,COALESCE(a.after_id, a.before_id) AS id_a
            ,COALESCE(a.after_agency_id, a.before_agency_id) AS id_b
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_a, id_b ORDER BY ts_ms DESC ) as rn
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                record_content:payload:before.id::VARCHAR          AS before_id,
                record_content:payload:before.agency_id::VARCHAR   AS before_agency_id,
                record_content:payload:after.id::VARCHAR           AS after_id,
                record_content:payload:after.agency_id::VARCHAR    AS after_agency_id,
                record_content:payload:after::VARIANT              AS payload,
                record_content:payload:source.ts_ms::INT           AS ts_ms,
                record_content:payload:op::VARCHAR                 AS op,
            FROM raw.message_stream
    `   ) as A
    ) AS B
    WHERE b.rn = 1   
) AS ps 
    ON (p.id = ps.after_id AND p.agency_id = ps.after_agency_id) OR
       (p.id = ps.before_id AND p.agency_id = ps.before_agency_id)
WHEN MATCHED AND ps.op = 'd' 
    THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND ps.op IN ('u', 'r') 
    THEN UPDATE SET p.payload = ps.payload, p.ts_ms = ps.ts_ms
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ps.op IN ('c', 'r', 'u') 
    THEN INSERT (p.id, p.agency_id, p.payload, p.ts_ms) 
        VALUES (ps.after_id, ps.after_agency_id, ps.payload, ps.ts_ms);
```

and with the joins as I suspect would work for you data.. on cloned tables, just to see how the performance impact is:

```
MERGE INTO target.message AS p
USING (
    (
    SELECT 
        --b.before_id,
        --b.before_agency_id,
        b.after_id,
        b.after_agency_id,
        b.payload,
        b.ts_ms,
        b.op,
        b.id_a,
        b.id_b
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            A.*
            ,COALESCE(a.after_id, a.before_id) AS id_a
            ,COALESCE(a.after_agency_id, a.before_agency_id) AS id_b
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_a, id_b ORDER BY ts_ms DESC ) as rn
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                record_content:payload:before.id::VARCHAR          AS before_id,
                record_content:payload:before.agency_id::VARCHAR   AS before_agency_id,
                record_content:payload:after.id::VARCHAR           AS after_id,
                record_content:payload:after.agency_id::VARCHAR    AS after_agency_id,
                record_content:payload:after::VARIANT              AS payload,
                record_content:payload:source.ts_ms::INT           AS ts_ms,
                record_content:payload:op::VARCHAR                 AS op,
            FROM raw.message_stream
    `   ) as A
    ) AS B
    WHERE b.rn = 1   
) AS ps 
    ON p.id = ps.id_a AND p.agency_id = ps.id_b
WHEN MATCHED AND ps.op = 'd' 
    THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND ps.op IN ('u', 'r') 
    THEN UPDATE SET p.payload = ps.payload, p.ts_ms = ps.ts_ms
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ps.op IN ('c', 'r', 'u') 
    THEN INSERT (p.id, p.agency_id, p.payload, p.ts_ms) 
        VALUES (ps.after_id, ps.after_agency_id, ps.payload, ps.ts_ms);
```

### Another thing to try to "get thought the backlog"

Split the task into to steps, just for now, make a temp table that is the first half:

```
CREATE TABLE perm_but_call_temp_table AS
   SELECT 
        record_content:payload:before.id::VARCHAR          AS before_id,
        record_content:payload:before.agency_id::VARCHAR   AS before_agency_id,
        record_content:payload:after.id::VARCHAR           AS after_id,
        record_content:payload:after.agency_id::VARCHAR    AS after_agency_id,
        record_content:payload:after::VARIANT              AS payload,
        record_content:payload:source.ts_ms::INT           AS ts_ms,
        record_content:payload:op::VARCHAR                 AS op,
        COALESCE(after_id, before_id) AS id_a
        COALESCE(after_agency_id, before_agency_id) AS id_b
    FROM raw.message_stream
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_a, id_b ORDER BY ts_ms DESC ) = 1
```

then merge that into your main table.

```
MERGE INTO target.message AS p
USING perm_but_call_temp_table AS ps 
    ON p.id = ps.id_a AND p.agency_id = ps.id_b
WHEN MATCHED AND ps.op = 'd' 
    THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND ps.op IN ('u', 'r') 
    THEN UPDATE SET p.payload = ps.payload, p.ts_ms = ps.ts_ms
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ps.op IN ('c', 'r', 'u') 
    THEN INSERT (p.id, p.agency_id, p.payload, p.ts_ms) 
        VALUES (ps.after_id, ps.after_agency_id, ps.payload, ps.ts_ms);
```

which will give you an idea "where the problem is" the first or the second operation. and it will also let you merge into clones, and test if the equi join version runs faster, and the results are the same.

Comment: Right, so apart form the changes to the query our best bet is to just run a larger warehouse? That's how I am understanding your answer :)

Comment: Well it could be something going wrong also. Can you show the profile trace window. The one that shows the in outs rows from each node.

Comment: Updated the question with a snapshot of the query profile. This is for a slightly different table which has fewer rows (6M in stream). It's running the same `MERGE` query albeit writing to a different table. This is on an XL warehouse.

Comment: On your second approach where you suggest creating a temp table, how would the scheduling of tasks work? Say I create a task tree as follows: temp table → merge. And it is the merge taking forever to run. With overlapping executions set to false, would the "temp table" task run twice if it finishes execution quickly?

Comment: I am asking because there is the Snowflake Sink Connector which will continuously ingest data from Kafka into the source table and keep populating the stream.

Comment: I would turn off the Tasks that normally drain the Stream, manually drain it, with one read operation into the temp table, any updates to the stream will wait till after you start the Task again. Aka the "temp" table is just trying to help fix the backlog, BUT if you are getting 50M rows of this nature a day, you will be a faster process. perhaps another reason to workout if the equi-join option works for you.

Comment: I rewrote the query like you said and it ran spiffy fast on an XL warehouse. It really was the join which was killing performance.